# Treemap visualisation with PHP?

Tags: php, treemap, visualization

There seem to be examples for TreeMaps for almost every language but PHP. Has anyone got a link to some basic code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://www.neurofuzzy.net/2006/04/28/treemap-php-source-code/
- http://powernerd.blogspot.com/2007/06/treemaps-with-php.html