# Heat maps and Economic indicators

Tags: heatmap, yahoo-finance, indicator, economics

I do a small website contains the data about stock marker . i ill get stock data's from yahoo finance api and also for finance charts. now i  need to show the economic indicators and financial  heat maps like  http://finviz.com/map.ashx where can i get the source for it? is any api available or the yahoo itself provide these details. i need to do it in php framework(yii). i have referred some sites but i didn't get a clear idea on that.

Comment: Did you find an API?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Economic Indicators, you could take a look at datasets on DataHub.io platform - it is the place where most important indicators from various sources are standardized and provided in CSV/JSON formats. It has an API for fetching data.

You can find all available Economic Data here:

https://datahub.io/awesome/economic-data

And here is the instructions about the API:

https://datahub.io/docs/getting-started/getting-data

Usually, you'd also need some reference data such as the list of countries or country codes. You could find it here:

https://datahub.io/awesome/reference-data

Answer (score -1):

The chart you link to is called a TreeMap (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treemapping), not a heatmap. Searching for treemap brings up a previous question for php. The answer given there is http://powernerd.blogspot.co.uk/2007/06/treemaps-with-php.html

(ref [Treemap visualisation with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139137/treemap-visualisation-with-php).)

But hopefully with the correct search terms for Google you will be able to find other solutions!